# How to recursively reverse and print a large txt file using C

Tags: c, recursion, multidimensional-array, txt

I am new to programming so I am struggling a bit here. Currently my errors pertain to my 2D array being incompatible. The purpose of this code is to read in a large text file, and recursively print it backwards character by character.

My action plan is to store the data read in from the txt file into a 2D array. This data will be stored using a recursive function, then printed to another txt file after.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char fillArray(FILE* fileIn, char array, int rowCount, int colCount); 

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
        
    int rowCount = 50000; 
    int colCount = 100; //arbitrary numbers chosen 
    char  array[rowCount][colCount];        
    
        FILE* fileIn = NULL;
        fileIn = fopen(argv[1], "r");       

        if (fileIn == NULL){
            
            printf("ERROR FILE DOES NOT OPEN");
            return 1; //to exit
            
        }   
/*  array = (char**)(malloc(rowCount*colCount* sizeof(*array)));
        if(!array){
            printf("ERROR: malloc wasnt assigned");
            return 1;
        }   */
        fillArray(fileIn, array, rowCount, colCount);       
        
            
        fclose(fileIn);
            
        
     free(array); 
    
    return 0;
}
char fillArray(FILE* fIn, char array, int rowCount, int colCount){
    if(rowCount == 0 && colCount == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        fscanf(fIn,"%s", &array[rowCount][colCount]);   
        if(array[rowCount][colCount] == '\n'){
            return fillArray(fIn, array, rowCount-1, colCount-1);
        }
        else{
            return fillArray(fIn, array, rowCount, colCount-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need a 2-D array for this. A simpler 1-D array should be enough.

Comment: Your immediate problem is that `"%s"` in `scanf()` does never ever read a `'\n'` (or a space for that matter) so the contents of `array` will never have a newline.

Comment: That sounds vaguely familiar and now I feel dumb. When you say I only need a 1D array do you mean store character by character including the newlines?

Comment: Yes, save the file in one big string ... like `"line 1\nline 2\n....\nline 435\n"` and then print character-by-character from the end (you may need to tweak the newlines).

Comment: Why are you wanting to use recursion?

Comment: `ERROR FILE DOES NOT OPEN` is the canonical example of a useless error message. Try `if( (fileIn = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL ) { perror(argv[1]); exit(1); }`

Comment: William Pursell, these are part of the guidelines I must follow. Recursion, and the Error message format.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share a representative snippet of the text file and desired outcome, please? Recursion is a poor choice here--you can blow the stack if the text file is too large and it adds overhead. Seems like the CS educational system forcing recursion on a problem it's ill-suited for yet again...

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to figure it out by counting the amount of characters in the document, creating a 1-D array (as recommended) and used recursion to print backwards. The point of the project was to understand memory and why recursion "wouldn't" be useful in this situation Thank you again!!